# How does one calculate the p value for a two tailed chi square test with degree freedom of 1?

Tags: p-value, chi-squared-test

How does one calculate the p value for a two tailed chi square test with degree freedom of 1?

```
prop.test(matrix(c(9,17,5,13), nrow = 2), correct = F)
2-sample test for equality of proportions without continuity correction

data:  matrix(c(9, 17, 5, 13), nrow = 2)
X-squared = 0.22922, df = 1, p-value = 0.6321
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.2311216  0.3835026
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2 
0.6428571 0.5666667
```

With chisquare statistic of `0.22922`  I get a cumulative distribution density of `0.36` with this code

```
pchisq(0.22922, df=1, lower.tail = T)
```

I don't think I could just `2*0.36` since it's not a normal distribution... how do I find the complementary of the upper tail so that the number will be equal to `0.6321` as shown by `prop.test`?

Comment: Did you try `pchisq(0.22922, df=1, lower.tail = F)` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most cases, one does not calculate the p-value for a two-tailed chi-square test. In most cases, one computes two-tailed p-values from PDFs symmetric around the mean (e.g., normal or Student's *t*). Exceptions are provided in comments below.

With df $< 90$  the chi-square PDF is not symmetric, it is skewed to the right. To get the `0.6321` (the upper tail), one would do:

`1 - pchisq(0.22922, df=1, lower.tail = T)`

which yields an identical result as:

`pchisq(0.22922, df=1, lower.tail = F)`.

That is, upper and lower tail add up to 1, by definition.

In response to your comment below, about the `prop.test` function giving a different result for the following 2x2 table of counts (successes in 1st, failures in 2nd column; group 1 in 1st, group 2 in 2nd row):

> ```
> O <- matrix(c(9, 5, 17, 13), nrow = 2)
> O
>         [,1] [,2] 
>   [1,]    9   17 
>   [2,]    5   13
> ```

With `prop.test`, this can be tested in a one-sided manner (prop. in first group is larger than in second group, vice versa), or in a two-sided manner (proportions are not equal between groups). The latter can be tested using a chi-square distribution, where the expected counts (given the null hypothesis of equal group counts) are compared with observed counts ($\sum \frac{(O-E)^2}{E}$). Expected counts under a null-hypothesis of equal proportions (14 successes out of 44 trials, 26 trials out of 44 in first group) would be:

> ```
> E <- matrix(c((14/44)*c(26, 18), (30/44)*c(26, 18)), nrow = 2)
> E
>             [,1]     [,2]
>    [1,] 8.272727 17.72727
>    [2,] 5.727273 12.27273
> ```

> ```
> sum((O - E)^2/E)
> [1] 0.2292226
> ```

Note how this quantity evaluates the *difference* between expected and observed (thus, a two-sided test), not whether the observed number of successes is higher or lower in one group than the other (a one-sided test). It thus yields the same result as:

> ```
> prop.test(O, nrow = 2), correct = F, alternative = "two.sided") 
>
>   2-sample test for equality of proportions without continuity correction
>
> data:  O
> X-squared = 0.22922, df = 1, p-value = 0.6321
> alternative hypothesis: two.sided
> 95 percent confidence interval:
>  -0.2077665  0.3445186
> sample estimates:
>    prop 1    prop 2 
> 0.3461538 0.2777778
> ```

Note that if one specifies a one-sided test for equal proportions (`alternative = "less"` of `alternative = "greater"`), the same test statistic is used (i.e., same value for `X-squared` is reported). However, under the hood the code then uses the square root of the test statistic and a normal distribution to obtain the p-value:

> ```
> pnorm(sqrt(0.22922), lower.tail = TRUE)
> [1] 0.6839486
> pnorm(sqrt(0.22922), lower.tail = FALSE)
> [1] 0.3160514
> ```

Because if $Z$ follows a standard normal distribution, then $Z^2$ follows a chi-square distribution with one degree of freedom.

Comment: You mean the p value given is basically for right tail?

Comment: @KKW Yes. The default of function `pchisq` is `lower.tail=TRUE`, which returns the left tail, or $P[X \leq x]$. With `lower.tail=FALSE`, it returns the right tail, or $P[X>x]$.

Comment: A good answer in general, but the following statement seems to me to be incorrect: "One can compute two-tailed p-values only from PDFs symmetric around the mean...".

Comment: @MarjoleinFokkema this is weird, when I tried `prop.test(matrix(c(9,5,17,13),nrow = 2), correct = F, alternative = "less")` it showed a different p value 
```2-sample test for equality of proportions without continuity correction

data:  matrix(c(9, 5, 17, 13), nrow = 2)
X-squared = 0.22922, df = 1, p-value = 0.6839
alternative hypothesis: less
95 percent confidence interval:
 -1.0000000  0.3001222
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2 
0.3461538 0.2777778 
```

Comment: -1. The first three sentences do not make much sense to me. You *can* obtain a two-tailed p-value for an asymmetric distribution (including $\chi^2$) and the $\chi^2$ distribution does have two tails.

Comment: @RichardHardy Indeed you *can* but usually you do not *do* so in most chi squared tests, unless your alternative hypothesis is that the experimenter cheated and fixed the results to be closer to the assumed distribution than were actually observed

Comment: @Henry, I have used two-tailed chi-squared tests when assessing i.i.d. random number generators (RNGs). A RNG that generates numbers forming certain patterns are no good, but so are those that output number without patterns that would occur naturally (too good to be true). E.g. a "coin" that delivers exactly 50% heads in every sample is suspect. I bet there are other sensible uses of two-tailed chi-squared tests, too.

Comment: @KKW I've updated the answer in order to address your 2nd comment.

Comment: @RichardHardy, Ben & Henry: Thank you for your insightful comments! I was overlooking some options and have adjusted the answer accordingly.

Comment: I still do not see why symmetry of the distribution should be regarded as a fundamental consideration for determining whether two-sided p-value makes sense. Also, I still cannot help but see two tails of a $\chi^2$ distribution rather than one. But perhaps it is just me...

Comment: @MarjoleinFokkema, why should it be relevant? Depending on what type of $H_1$ we have, we could either deviate from $H_0$ in two ways or in one way. Thus, we look at both tails or just one tail accordingly. The shape of the null distribution does not enter this consideration.

Comment: @RichardHardy Thanks, agreed! Makes more sense to call it two tails, and this does provide a neater perspective. (previous comment removed to avoid extensive discussion).

Comment: @Richard I believe the shape of the null is crucial.  You appear to assume (implicitly) that all two-tailed tests should be symmetric in probability, but that's not necessarily the case in the N-P formulation, where the critical regions (and therefore how the p-value is split between the tails) depend on the specifics of the alternative hypothesis.

Comment: @MarjoleinFokkema Thanks for the explaination of the under the hood Z^2, I do wonder the default two.tailed calculates p value using `2*pnorm(sqrt(0.22922), lower.tail = FALSE)`

Comment: @whuber, I was talking about symmetry but wrote *shape* in one instance (in my last comment), and that was indeed too general to be true. I have not been assuming symmetry in my argument, though, as the $\chi^2$ distribution of my previous two-tail example is asymmetric. But I understand that the specifics of $H_1$ matter for determining the critical regions in the N-P formulation.

Comment: @Richard The symmetry I refer to is not symmetry in shape, but symmetry in *probabilities.*  The critical region in such cases is chosen to include half the probability in the upper tail and half in the lower tail.

Comment: @KWW The default `two.sided` would return `pchisq(0.22922, df = 1, lower.tail = FALSE)`, which is probably computationally cheaper. If you print `prop.test`, the last 14 lines of code show the computations.

Comment: @whuber, thank you for the elaboration. Marjolein was talking about symmetric distributions, and I do not see what is so fundamental about the symmetry of a distribution when it comes to figuring out whether we shall use a one-sided or a two-sided test. Again, does my example of $\chi^2$ not constitute a valid counterexample?

Comment: @Richard I have no problem with your counterexample, but find it *incomplete.*  I don't follow your point about symmetric distributions, because isn't it the *asymmetric* chi-squared distribution that is being discussed?

Comment: @whuber, the discussion started by Marjolein claiming (roughly) that symmetry of the distribution is a prerequisite for a two-tailed test. I criticized that claim and provided the counterexample. That is my main point.

Comment: @MarjoleinFokkema Now I am a tad confused... if my null hypothesis is that there is no relationship between the 2 categorical variables, then i should set my alternative to greater, correct? When would I want to set it as two.sided if df=1?

Comment: @KWW: If your null-hypothesis is no difference in proportions between group 1 and 2 (i.e., no association), use "two.sided". If your null-hypothesis is that group 1 has larger proportion of successes than group 2, use "greater". If you null-hypothesis is that group 2 has larger proportion of successes than group 1, use "less".

Comment: @MarjoleinFokkema Ah I see! Thank you for the clarification. One more thing to clarify, say we use `chisq.test` instead which does not allow you to set `two.sided`, `less`, or `greater`, and since `prop.test` uses `pnorm` to calculate the `less` and `greater` p_value, can I safely assume that `two.sided` (if null hypothesis is that there is no difference/association between grp 1 and 2) & upper tail (if null-hypothesis that group 1 has larger proportion of success than group 2) in general (or `chisq.test`) is the same as `upper tail` , and should have the same `p value`?

Comment: @KWW Yes, `chisq.test` with `upper.tail=T` should yield the same p-value as `prop.test` with `alternative = "greater"`.